# Brake lights on '94 Honda Prelude stuck on

Tags: electrical, honda, brakes, lights

All 3 brake lights on my Prelude seem to be permanently stuck on. This occurs all of the time - the lights stay on even if there is no key in the ignition. I've had to disconnect the battery.

Would anyone know of a way to fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow the brake pedal arm up under the dash. This may require some plastic trim to be removed. Looking up you should find a switch that is activated by the brake pedal arm. This switch may have failed or fallen out of the mount.

Comment: Thanks - your are correct! For anyone else who is having trouble like this with this particular model of car, the switch is activated when released - ie when the brake is 'off' the switch is held down but when the pedal is pushed, the switch is released. I found that there was a plastic pad connecting the pedal to this switch. The plastic had disintegrated. I replaced mine with a small bolt of equal thickness.